# Shadow Detached from Object

Tags: shadows

I'm very new to Blender. After creating this chair, I added a flat plain for the ground and have confirmed the my chair is snapped to the ground plain. When I added a light, I noticed the shadows are detached from the chair legs, as if it were hovering above the ground. Any idea what may be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the light you're using to light the scene, click the lightbulb on the properties panel, and go down to where it says "Shadow". Under that section, check the box that says "contact shadows"

[image]

Comment: Thank you Christopher. Well, it seems so obvious now. LOL